# Should I $mysqli->close a connection after each page load, if PHP runs via FCGI?

Tags: php, mysqli, fastcgi

I run PHP via FCGI - that is my web server spawns several PHP processes and they keep running for like 10,000 requests until they get recycled.

My question is - if I've a `$mysqli->connect` at the top of my PHP script, do I need to call `$mysqli->close` in when I'm about to end running the script?

Since PHP processes are open for a long time, I'd image each `$mysqli->connect` would leak 1 connection, because the process keeps running and no one closes the connection.

Am I right in my thinking or not? Should I call `$mysqli->close`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When PHP exits it closes the database connections gracefully.

The only reason to use the close method is when you want to terminate a database connection that you´ll not use anymore, and you have lots of things to do: Like processing and streaming the data, but if this is quick, you can forget about the close statement.

Putting it in the end of a script means redundancy, no performance or memory gain.

Comment: yes, but PHP doesn't exit in my case. Web server spawns them up and then keeps pushing them things to run without making the processes exit. The processes stay open for 10,000 requests. (At least that's what I understand by FCGI.)

Comment: As far as I can think, GC will clear those out. Process wont exit but memory has to be cleared between script executions. Otherwise it would be a real security problem since also the public variables etc. would stay in scope.

Answer (score 3):

In a bit more detail, specifically about FastCGI:

FastCGI keeps PHP processing running between requests. FastCGI is good at reducing CPU usage by leveraging your server's available RAM to keep PHP scripts in memory instead of having to start up a separate PHP process for each and every PHP request.

Answer (score 3):

FastCGI will start a master process and as many forks of that master process as you have defined and yes those forked processes might life for a long time. This means in effect that the process doesn't have to start-up the complete PHP process each time it needs to execute a script. But it's not like you think that your scripts are now running all the time. There is still a start-up and shutdown phase each time a script has to be executed. At this point things like global variables (e.g. `$_POST` and `$_GET`) are populated etc. You can execute functions each time your process shuts down via `register_shutdown_function()`.

If you aren't using persistent database connections and aren't closing database connections, nothing bad will happen. As Colin Schoen explained, PHP will eventually close them during shutdown.

Still, I *highly* encourage you to close your connections because a correctly crafted program knows when the lifetime of an object is over and cleans itself up. It might give you exactly the milli- or nanosecond that you need to deliver something in time.

> Simply **always** create self-contained objects that are also cleaning up after they are finished with whatever they did.

Answer (score 2):

I've never trusted FCGI to close my database connections for me. One habit I learned in a beginners book many years ago is to always explicitly close my database connections.

Is not typing sixteen keystrokes worth the possible memory and connection leak? As far as I'm concerned its cheap insurance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have long running FastCGI processes, via e.g. php-fpm, you can gain performance by reusing your database connection inside each process and avoiding the cost of opening one.

Since you are most likely opening a connection at some point in your code, you should read up on how to have mysqli open a persistent connection and return it to you on subsequent requests managed by the same process.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

In this case you don't want to close the connection, else you are defeating the purpose of keeping it open. Also, be aware that each PHP process will use a separate connection so your database should allow for at least that number of connections to be opened simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in your way of thinking. It is still important to close connection to prevent memory/data leaks and corruption.

You can also lower the amount of scipts recycled each cycle, to stop for a connection close.

For example: each 2500 script runs, stop and close and reopen connection.

Also recommended: back up data frequently.

Hope I helped. Phantom